# Bulk update MySQL value with condition

Tags: mysql

I have a table called "posts", and there is a column called "slug" in it.
I want to change some value/slug.

In short "slug" column has values:

post-1 
post-2
post-3
post-4
post-5
post-6

I want to change like this:
UPDATE 'posts'
WHERE post-2 change to new-post-2
WHERE post-4 change to new-post-4
and so on.

what is the MySQL script to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If there's a functional relationship like you indicate:

```
UPDATE posts
SET slug=CONCAT('new-', slug)
WHERE
  slug IN ('post-2', 'post-4'...);
```